# Order of Telegram bot functions to listen (on, hears, command) & Type parameters in Telegraf

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegraf

I am trying create a telegram bot using **node.js** (**telegraf**). But I am facing problems while using `on`, `hears`, `command`. For Example, if I use `hears` before `command`, `hears` listens the command. sometimes it went `on`.

I modified my code to similar example. Here the command stringx not calling, but it calls to hears.

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

bot.on('text', (ctx) => ctx.reply(''))
bot.hears('string', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hey there'))
bot.command('stringx', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hello'))

bot.launch();
```

Similar things happened with `on('text',callback)`, `on('message',callback)`, `on('pinned_message',callback)`.

- What is the order of *type parameters* listening using `on`.(Source (Type parameters): https://telegraf.js.org/classes/Telegraf.html#on)?
- What is the order of placing `on`, `hears`, `command`?

*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: do you mean if you place **hear then command** both events, works.

Comment: but if you register listeners for **command then hear** it is not gonna work ?

Comment: @Abilogos , only hears is working

Comment: in the second case (command then hear)?

Comment: @Abilogos , Second case is working fine, i confused placing here and there, So I asked for correct, So i can use from next time

Comment: ok, I am writing the answer, it will take a couple of minutes

Comment: @Abilogos , also need order for type parameters of `on`

Answer (score 2):

You need to [call next() to continue the middleware chain](https://telegraf.js.org/index.html#middleware) or else the first satisfied query will be the only one that runs.

```
await next() // runs next middleware
```